# Write php file with "$_SERVER text" via phpseclib: SSH2

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

It`s need to create file "index.php" in ssh session.

Used: "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0",

```
$ssh = new SSH2("192.168.138.5", 22);
$ssh->login("user", "mypass");
$ssh->write("cd /home/user/\n");
$ssh->read('[prompt]');

$ssh->exec("cat > index.php <<EOF
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
EOF\n");
$ssh->disconnect();
unset($ssh);
```

But result is:

```
<?php
include(['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
```

How to write "$_SERVER" text to file in ssh session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
include(\\$" . "_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add backslash \ before $ sign
\$_SERVER